# Change sourcefiles listed in elf debug info

Tags: elf, dwarf

Basically I want to be able to change the path to the source file in debug dwarf section in a elf binary.

Answer (score 2):

> Basically I want to be able to change the path to the source file in debug dwarf section in a elf binary.

What's stopping you?

The path is stored in the `.debug_str` section of the binary, as a `NUL`-terminated string. You can find the section offset from e.g. `readelf -S`, and edit the string with `emacs`. Or write a program to do that.

Comment: if only it were that easy. the dwarf sections cross references i.e. debug_info has offsets into debug_line. so if you change debug_line you have to modify the other sections to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case your answer is gdb (or other debugger) related, there's often a way to change the source path -- in gdb you can see `set substitute-path` via http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html

Answer (score 1):

debugedit is a program included in the RPM package that should be helpful.

Comment: It is worth to note that `debugedit` refuses to create longer paths as the result of re-writing