# Relocate files in .debug_line section

Tags: c++, dwarf, objcopy

Is it possible to change the file paths in a `.debug_line` section in an ELF file?

I'm trying to set up [Debug Fission](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DebugFission), so far I have `my_library.so` (in release mode, with no debug info) and `my_library.so.dbg` (with debug symbols). I've linked the two with

```sh
objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=my_library.so.dbg
```

And I can see that gdb is correctly picking up symbols and line info from `my_library.so.dbg` both via manual inspection and checking the file accesses via

```
strace -o log gdb program_that_loads_my_library.so
cat log | grep my_library.so.dbg  # I see a 'stat' that returns a file
```

However, the build for `my_library.so.dbg` encodes file paths at a different location than I use to debug. Is there a way to relocate the file paths in `my_library.so.dbg` so that I can point it to an arbitrary directory? More specifically, all the files are in some directory during the build, say `/build_dir/...`, but when debugging I want to replace this with `/home/myuser/local_checkout/...`. Is this possible with `objcopy`? I didn't see anything about it in the [manual](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Eprabal/teaching/eecs373-f10/readings/Binary_Utilities.pdf)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change sourcefiles listed in elf debug info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582447/change-sourcefiles-listed-in-elf-debug-info)